# Adding Integration Services to Previous SQL Server Install

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add integration services to an instance of SQL Server on my machine. When attempting to do so I get the following error:

[image]

Some basic googling around has not yielded anything helpful. Does anyone here have any insight?

Comment: How are you trying to install SSIS? Also, why SQL Server 2012, which only has a couple of years of extended support left.

Comment: @Larnu I am attempting to do so using the SQL Server Installation Center. As for 2012, it's just what we use for now. No say in the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if *sqlncli.msi* exists in `%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK`. If it does not exist use the subsequent steps to download, uninstall, and re-install it to resolve this error.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms131321(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

> The SQL Server Native Client header and library files (sqlncli.h and sqlncli10.lib) are installed in the following location:

> > %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK

> You can distribute (install) SQL Server Native Client through sqlncli.msi. You might have to install SQL Server Native Client when you deploy an application. One way to install multiple packages in what seems to the user to be a single installation is to use chainer and bootstrapper technology. For more information, see Authoring a Custom Bootstrapper Package for Visual Studio 2005 and Adding Custom Prerequisites.

> The x64 and Itanium versions of sqlncli.msi also install the 32-bit version of SQL Server Native Client. If your application targets a platform other than the one it was developed on, you can download versions of sqlncli.msi for x64, Itanium, and x86 from the Microsoft Download Center.

> When you invoke sqlncli.msi, only the client components are installed by default. The client components are are files that support running an application that was developed using SQL Server Native Client. To also install the SDK components, specify ADDLOCAL=All on the command line. For example:

> > msiexec /i sqlncli.msi ADDLOCAL=ALL APPGUID={0CC618CE-F36A-415E-84B4-FB1BFF6967E1}

**Steps to take if sqlncli.msi does not exist in the documented path**

1. Go to Control Panel and uninstall `SQL Server 2012 Native Client`
2. Download `Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Native Client - QFE` https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50402 and install
3. Use SQL Server Installation Center to add SSIS

Comment: Wouldn't this be downgrading to an older version of sql server native client? The download from that link says "A Newer version already exists on this machine". (I did not uninstall original version before checking)

Comment: @MaxB after initial install yes it is, but, you can apply Windows Updates/Patches after installing it so it becomes the equivalent to whats currently installed. Your getting the error because there is already is a version already installed+patched.

Comment: Is there any risk to my sql server instances running on my machine?

Comment: If you have anything with *connections strings* that use **OLE DB\SQL Server Native Client**  (ConnectionStrings containing ` "Provider = SQLNCLI11.1"`), then yes temporarily if a process like SSIS or an app tried to run and connect while your doing the un-install, re-install process..